# What does this do in assembly

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

My teacher wants us to have a basic understanding of assembly, because later down the road, that might be helpful. I'm fine with that, but my college provides zero documentation on the subject, apart from 4 small examples. I'm trying to figure out what is happening in this one:

```
.DEVICE ATmega32

.CSEG
main:

ldi    ZL,low(varclist<<1)
ldi    ZH,high(varclist<<1)

.CSEG
varclist:
.db    1, 2
.db    3, 4
.db    5, 6
.db    7, 8
.db    9, 0
```

I'm am working in AVR studio 5, and looking at the 'processor' tab. I can't seem to find any relation between the values in 'varclist', and the hexadecimal values the registers are showing. How do i look at this?

I would expect the Z register to contain 0x0100 as i would imagine the 'most-significant' bit to be the first one declared, and the least significant the last declared. I'm seeing 0x0070, however. I'm not sure what the shifting does, though.

Comment: As it is for your homework, I think you should add that tag. For the same reason, telling you exactly what the code is probably not the best way to help you. Can you tell what you think should be present in your registers and what are the value that you get? Once you've done this, we could certainly explain what was wrong in your reasoning :)

Comment: That is fair, i'm not looking for the answer, i'd like to understand. I'll add more information.

Comment: I recommend assembling, then disassembling the code.  Then look at the avr instruction set manual for information on each instruction.  You should be able to figure out between the avr instruction set document and the core/cpu chapter in the atmega32 datasheet/manual what the z register is, how it maps to gprs, and what the instruction is actually doing as coded.  from there work backwards to the assembly language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your wondering about the shifting, what it does is shift all the bits by one to the left adding a zero as first bit. In other words it multiplies by 2 the high (resp. low) value of the variable `varclist`.

`varclist` here in your program is the address of the array of bytes [ 0x01, 0x02, ... 0x00 ] in memory => `varclist` is a pointer to the first byte of this array. To obtain the original address, we just need to divide by 2 (reverse operation of the multiply) and we obtain

```
0x0070 >> 1 = 0000 0000 0111 0000 >> 1 = 0000 0000 0011 1000 = 0x0038
```

So the `varclist` address was `0x0038`. I don't know how you thought this was 0x0100 but I hope you now understand the code.

I think this address is multiplied by 2 because addresses to the program storage space are expressed in word offset, in which case you'll need to multiply by 2 to get the address in a byte offset. Later you can load that byte (the first byte of your array) into `r0`thanks to the `LPM` assembly instruction.

I would recommend you read the chapter 5.2 of [this pdf](http://www.avr-asm-download.de/beginner_en.pdf) and possibly the other chapters as well. The [AVR Assembler User Guide](http://www.atmel.com/atmel/acrobat/doc1022.pdf) is also probably a good bet.